# Facebook Video Embed Controll with Javascript (Play / Pause)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Please Help me how can i use this api correctly with the code they give in the url below

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api/#control-reference
```

[image]

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
                          appId      : '17xxxxxxxxxx',
                          xfbml      : true,
                          version    : 'v3.5'
                        });

                    var ssp_video_player;
                    var time = jQuery(this).attr("time");


                    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
                      if (msg.type === 'video') {
                        ssp_video_player = msg.instance;
                      }
                      ssp_video_player.seek(600);

                    });

                };
```

When i loading page video skip / seek works but after loading complete i did not able to control player with this variable for example

```
ssp_video_player.play(); or 
ssp_video_player.pause(); etc.
```

Or any other way so i can control the facebook video player ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to control via `ssp_video_player` outside the function is because the variable is defined locally. You should define `ssp_video_player` outside the function. Also, make sure you are not accessing the play/pause before the asynchronous function is executed and the value of ssp_video_player is set.

```
var ssp_video_player;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
       appId      : '17xxxxxxxxxx',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v3.5'
    });

    var time = jQuery(this).attr("time");


    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
            ssp_video_player = msg.instance;
        }
        ssp_video_player.seek(600);

     });
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.... Actually i did it as you said put variable before function start but still not able to access it at console :(

Comment: Your JS fiddle is not working since you are accessing play property before the async function is executed and my_video_player is set. You should check if player is defined and play property exists before trying to play it. Check the working JS fiddle where it auto plays out side the fb function https://jsfiddle.net/L0kndw68/5/. It keeps checking if play exists and the moment the player is set, it plays the video. Not the best way to do it but just to illustrate the concept. Best way would be to play when ready is executed.

Comment: Just one last favor if you can please i am passing variable with seek(time) but getting invalid argument please see at https://jsfiddle.net/7t6kyvbg/ at the video there a timestamp link and jquery code also there please see if you can help

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("a.ssp-timestamp").click(function(){
     var time = jQuery(this).attr("time");
     my_video_player.seek(time);
    });
   });

Comment: uncaught exception: Error: Invalid argument

Comment: Hey, the issue is that when you retrieve attributes from DOM they are string values by default. the seek function does not like string arguments and hence it complains. Just cast it to an int and it should work. See https://jsfiddle.net/Lfzr7e2p/